# Need to invoke the jQuery function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

"I have a function which needs to be called only once when one of the inputs of the form gets dirty(changed).once this function is called,it shouldn't be called again.I am trying to use the .off() feature but this is also disabling the form input changes.Below is the code. "

```
    $("#FormId :input").on('change', function () {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return true;
            };

        $('#FormId :input').off('change');
    });
```

Comment: You can just use [`one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one)

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`:

```
$("#FormId :input").on("change", function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return true;
    };
    $(this).off("change");
});
```

There's also jQuery's [`.one`](https://api.jquery.com/one) method:

```
$("#FormId :input").one("change", function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return true;
    };
});
```

Comment: Hello Jack...I have Tried both these Solutions....The First Solution Disables the future Input(which has invoked the jquery function) Change events  .....whereas the second solution will run for all the input changes only once....i need a solution which would not disable the Input Change Events and also the jquery function has to run only once for the whole form input changes